# How to encode a video response in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, video-encoding

In a request that I made I received a byte response and I know it is a response of a video. and it's status code was 200. And I don't know how to use it. I mean I tried to encode it into `utf-8` and then save it to a file but it is not playable. media players is unable to read it's content here's the request that I made

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://bcboltsony-a.akamaihd.net/media/v1/hls/v4/aes128/5182475815001/4ded6ac4-6f8b-4da2-8194-db2391d5e331/164fe5c5-15a3-4997-b4c6-7dd4b95f9c57/92410c6d-c565-4341-8650-1d40a795ece2/5x/segment1.ts?akamai_token=exp=1589337578~acl=/media/v1/hls/v4/aes128/5182475815001/4ded6ac4-6f8b-4da2-8194-db2391d5e331/164fe5c5-15a3-4997-b4c6-7dd4b95f9c57/92410c6d-c565-4341-8650-1d40a795ece2/*~hmac=bf9745f2a9b51c04d59eb9955de20dcf1b4c8c7e434ad0bdd639f2d80fa10ecc')

open('E:/video.mp4', 'wb').write(bytes(resp.text, encoding='utf-8'))
```

how to convert this response to a watchable format

Answer (score 1):

Try using wget which can help download files 10x easier.
Here is a simple code with your situation:

```
import wget
url = "https://bcboltsony-a.akamaihd.net/media/v1/hls/v4/aes128/5182475815001/4ded6ac4-6f8b-4da2-8194-db2391d5e331/164fe5c5-15a3-4997-b4c6-7dd4b95f9c57/92410c6d-c565-4341-8650-1d40a795ece2/5x/segment1.ts?akamai_token=exp=1589337578~acl=/media/v1/hls/v4/aes128/5182475815001/4ded6ac4-6f8b-4da2-8194-db2391d5e331/164fe5c5-15a3-4997-b4c6-7dd4b95f9c57/92410c6d-c565-4341-8650-1d40a795ece2/*~hmac=bf9745f2a9b51c04d59eb9955de20dcf1b4c8c7e434ad0bdd639f2d80fa10ecc"
wget.download(url, 'c:/users/Yourname/downloads/video.mp4')
```

If this does not work the problem of encoding may be on the url's side.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely right.But note that:

1. If you open this page in your explorer,you will find it is a `.ts` file instead of `.mp4` file.
2. Also,if you download it in the explorer directly, you also couldn't play it directly.In my PC, it also reminds me it has been damaged.

---

If you search it in the internet, `.ts` file is encrypted(In the page of your url,the way it encrypt is `AES128`).Maybe you need to take some measures.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with the below code. I hope it will work :).

```
open('E:/video.mp4', 'wb').write(resp.content)
```

Comment: please be kind to read the question before answering